# periodically check if a user is streaming, and do something based on that

Tags: python, python-3.6, twitch, discord.py

Im working on porting a Twitch bot to Discord, and I want to have the bot send a message if the owner of the Discord server is streaming. I haven't tried anything yet, but i had the idea of doing something like:

```
if server.owner.game.type == 1:  
  await chat(channel, message)
```

All I need to know now, is how to put this in a different thread, or do something so that this checks ever few seconds or minutes, and can send the message.

also i cant seem to get the code to show up as code :/

Comment: Have you read the [`background_task.py`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py) example bot?

Comment: thanks, i never expected that there would be something like this in the examples, then again i never really looked.